# Laravel Homestead error installing Gulp with elixir

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, homestead, laravel-elixir

When running `npm install` in homestead I get a long list of errors which start out with

```
npm ERR! UNKNOWN, mkdir '/home/vagrant/Code/gulp/node_modules/gulp-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-optipng/node_modules/optipng-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/bin-version-check/node_modules/bin-version/node_modules/find-versions'
```

My guess is the problem with the 260 character limit on paths that windows has and since all these folders map over to Windows from vagrant that is where the error is coming from.

Does anyone have an idea to get around this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you resolved it?

Comment: @c2 I installed on my host machine and made sure to do `npm install --global gulp`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are running an older Version of NPM, because `npm 3.0.0` uses a flat dependency tree specifically for windows users, see here:

[NPM 3.0.0 for Winndows Users](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5)

Just download node again from their site and reinstall it.